# How to search a Korean word made up of two or more syllables in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How do I search a Korean word made up of two or more syllables with Windows Explorer search? If I search for example 2-syllable-word [image: 2-syllable-word] ("world"), I get results for any files where filenames contain syllable-1 [image: syllable-1] and syllable-2 [image: syllable-2] even if they are not next to each other. So it brings up results like [image: example-result].

Adding quotes around the word did not help.

*Sorry for the weird format, Super User does not seem to allow Korean.

Comment: Korean characters were banned because of some spam wave in the past and somehow the ban wasn't lifted until now: [Korean characters not allowed](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14231/241386)